# Moving system versioned (temporal) MariaDB database from Windows to Linux

Tags: mariadb

After moving entire `data` directory from Win installation of MariaDB to Linux, partitioned temporal tables (or system versioned) cannot be seen by MariaDB.

Everything is ok with "tranditional" tables, MariaDB can access them on Linux. But for partitioned temporal tables there are problem:
on Windows partition data files are named like this: `<table name>#p#p_cur.ibd` (for current data partition)
but on Linux MariaDB expect this file to be named as `<table name>#P#p_cur.ibd`
and so MariaDB cannot use such partitions, it gives message:

> table do not exist in engine

Renaming .ibd file do not help, MariaDB cannot find file in this case.

Could anyone help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this should affect any partitioned tables. Can you confirm that?

On Windows, for some reason, InnoDB converts the `#P` into lower case. The table might be accessible on other platforms if you set `lower_case_table_names=2`. I think that such settings should not exist in the first place.

To rename the partitions to the correct names on InnoDB, it might be possible to do the following:

1. `CREATE TABLE t(a INT)ENGINE=InnoDB;` and copy the `t.frm` file to `tablename#p#p_cur.frm`
2. ``` RENAME TABLE ``#mysql50#tablename#p#p_cur`` TO ``#mysql50#tablename#P#p_cur``; ``` (Note: only single backticks instead of double ones. I had trouble with the formatting on StackOverflow.)
3. Remove the file `tablename#P#p_cur.frm`.
4. Repeat for each partition.
5. Finally, `DROP TABLE t;`

The special `#mysql50` prefix should pass the rest of the table name to the storage engine while bypassing the filename-safe encoding that was introduced in MySQL 5.1. That should allow direct access to the partitions. Normally the `#` is encoded as the sequence `@0023`, but the partitioning engine uses the raw `#P#` suffix.

In MySQL 4.1 and 5.0, the table names were encoded directly in UTF-8. In MySQL 4.0 (which was the stable release series when I started working on InnoDB internals), they could have been encoded directly in `latin1`, or perhaps non-ASCII characters in table names did not work on some file systems or operating systems.

Note: I think that the `.frm` file stores information of the storage engine. If you just copy the `tablename.frm` file of the partitioned table, it could be that only `ha_partition::rename_table()` would be invoked, instead of `ha_innobase::rename_table()`. We do want the rename operation to be performed by InnoDB, so that the table name will be renamed in its own data dictionary (the `SYS_TABLES` table, which is readable via `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES`).

Note: I did not test this. Please report back whether this worked.

Comment: thanks a lot for you detailed answer. I tried to apply a `lower_case_table_names=2` option, but MariaDB said that my fs is case sesitive (that's true for Linux), so it'll set this option to 0 to prevent problems.

Comment: But regarding the #mysql50 trick with renaming worked out, that's fantastic!
I beleive, this information will be very helpful for others in similar situation.

Comment: And indeed, MariaDB do name partition files in lower case (**#p#**) on Windows. They should fix this, I beleive.

Comment: I fully agree that the forced lower-casing of file names in InnoDB never was a good idea. But I am afraid that removing that code before removing the InnoDB internal data dictionary (with `strcmp()`-style binary collation on the `SYS_TABLES.NAME`) could cause huge trouble on upgrades on Windows. [MDEV-11655](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11655) has some random notes on that, and I think that the necessary first step is to implement crash-safe operations on `.frm` files, as noted in [MDEV-17567](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17567).